# How to modify and maintain an imported go dependency?

Tags: git, go, git-submodules, go-modules

In my go app(parent), I import a go library(child) through go get and copy it to the parent directory. For my use, I make some modifications in "child" for extending certain features. I use go module and use "replace" in go.mod to point to the local child(with extended features) path instead of the global $GOPATH.

I am confused how to constantly keep the child in sync with its upstream repo, while retaining my extended features.

```
//App directory    
Parent.go
--Child/ (copied from $GOPATH)
go.mod

//go.mod
replace github.com/xyz/child => ./Child
```

Setting up the child as a git-submodule works well in my system. But when the repo is pulled from another system, the child picks up it's go dependencies from `$GOPATH` from past versions and doesn't map to the correct version.

I an trying to setup git-submodule and go-module to work seamlessly for my app in any environment. I am trying to resolve this for more than a week now. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you should fork the repo, change import paths, keep it updated with upstream and use it.

Another option is to contribute to the third party library.

`replace` directive is more not for long-term usage but for debugging and non-standard situations.